# Error librería compilación al pasar al modo Release en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, studio, visual, compilacion

tengo una aplicación la cual utiliza una librería con controles de diseño, el caso es que la aplicación me funciona perfectamente cuando compilo en modo debug  pero cuando paso al modo release me arroja un error del siguiente tipo en todos los componentes:

```
CS0246: El nombre del tipo do del espacio de nombres 'xxx' no se encontró ¿falta auna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?
```

Me gustaría saber como poder solucionarlo y compilar en modo Release. Gracias.

Comment: Revisa la ubicación de la referencia que da error. Es probable que sea una referencia relativa a un `path` donde no tiene acceso en modo `release`. Es decir está visible en la carpeta `proyecto\bin\Debug` pero no en la carpeta `proyecto\bin\Release`

Comment: Revisa lo siguiente: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: puedes mencionar de cual libreria de controles se trata? el espacio de nombres que menciona en xxx es de esta libreria o se relaciona con esta? porque quizas sea por otra causa. Solo menciona ese unico error o hay otros listados, muchas veces puede ver un mensaje de error pero ese no es la causa original, sino que tienes otros que al resolverlo soluciona el resto

Comment: Puedes revisar también los .csproj, en ocasiones la configuración de compilación puede estar ruta en alguna ruta o en su defecto alguna dependencia con otros proyectos se haya configurado de forma errónea.